# how to Change Multiple getElementById?

Tags: javascript, html

its working but the only the first get elementbyid is working i mean it is the only code that change the value of id.

This is my html

```
<li ><a href="#Home" id="activehome" onclick="load_home()">HOME</a></li>
<li ><a href="#Products" id="inactiveproducts" onclick="load_products()">PRODUCTS</a>
```

**this is my script**

```
function load_home(){
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object class="slideshow"  type="text/html" data="home.html" style="overflow:hidden; width: 100%;   height:500px;" ></object>';

  if(document.getElementById("inactivehome")){
    document.getElementById("inactivehome").id = "activehome";
    document.getElementById("activeproducts").id = "inactiveproducts";
    document.getElementById("activeservice").id = "inactiveservice";
    document.getElementById("activeabout").id = "inactiveabout";
    document.getElementById("activecontactus").id = "inactiveproducts";
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have to change the Ids? Its not a good practice to do, what are you planning to achieve?

Comment: uses classes and nesting instead.

Comment: its my first time doing a one page website the content is changing except for the header. i dont know how to make a active and inactive to highlight the navigation menu.

Comment: The only element in the supplied markup that has an ID in the supplied function is *inactiveproducts*. There is no element with an ID *inactivehome*.

Comment: Are you trying to style the elements using the id?

Comment: better to use a class.. to be added or remove when the link is click and if you have time.. also try to read on jQuery..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably rewrite your code a bit and use less repetition.

I wrote a more optimized version of your code using an `active` class to denote active menu items while keeping IDs of each item intact.

See how much cleaner does the HTML look like when you move all the JS event listeners away from it.

I used a general load page function which loads the proper content (which is stored as a property of the `content` variable) and sets the menu item, so no code is repeated.

Here is my example:

```js
var pages = ['home', 'products', 'service', 'about', 'contactus'];

// add a click listener for each menu item
// instead of using onclick attributes 
for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById(pages[i]).addEventListener('click', function() {
     loadPage(this.id);
  })
}

// sets active class
function setActive(page) {
  for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(pages[i]).classList.remove('active');
  }
  document.getElementById(page).classList.add('active');
  
}

// general page loading function
function loadPage(id) {
  // load specific content
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = content[id];
  // set active menu item
  setActive(id);
}

// content for each page below
var content = {
  home: '<object class="slideshow"  type="text/html" data="home.html" style="overflow:hidden; width: 100%;   height:500px;" ></object>',
  products: '<p>Products Content Here</p>',
  service: '<p>Services Content Here</p>',
  about: '<p>About Us Content Here</p>',
  contactus: '<p>Contact Us Content Here</p>'
}
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
a.active, a:hover {
  color: green;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
#content {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li ><a href="#Home" id="home">HOME</a></li>
<li ><a href="#Products" id="products">PRODUCTS</a></li>
<li ><a href="#Service" id="service">SERVICE</a></li>
<li ><a href="#About" id="about">ABOUT</a></li>
<li ><a href="#Contactus" id="contactus">CONTACT US</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understands your question correctly what you want to achieve is change the appearance of the clicked element to indicate that its currently active? If thats the case the best approach would probably be to just toggle an active class since you dont appear to be doing anything specific with the IDs.

HTML

```
<li><a href="#Home" class="active" onclick="load_home()">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#Products" onclick="load_products()">PRODUCTS</a></li>
```

JS

```
$("a").click(function() {
  $(".active").removeclass();
  this.addClass("active");
);
```

CSS

```
.clicked {
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Why jQuery for something so simple?

Comment: its not needed for this example-code, however since this is only a tiny bit of the system of a whole it may be a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood what you asked, because your question is very poor. But I think that your second getElementById is not working because the id of the element is "activehome". So, you should change the id to "inactivehome", and it will go inside the if function and it will change the id of the other elements as you indicated.

HTML:

```
<li ><a href="#Home" id="inactivehome" onclick="load_home()">HOME</a></li>
<li ><a href="#Products" id="inactiveproducts" onclick="load_products()">PRODUCTS</a></li>
```

JS:

```
function load_home(){

document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<object class="slideshow"  type="text/html" data="home.html" style="overflow:hidden; width: 100%;   height:500px;" ></object>';

if(document.getElementById("inactivehome")){
document.getElementById("inactivehome").id = "activehome";
document.getElementById("activeproducts").id = "inactiveproducts";
document.getElementById("activeservice").id = "inactiveservice";
document.getElementById("activeabout").id = "inactiveabout";
document.getElementById("activecontactus").id = "inactiveproducts";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you can't as the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) specifies that the ID attribute must be unique in a page. As a result, having multiple same IDs means that your HTML is not valid.

I will suggest adding and removing class accordingly, i.e if you need `activeproducts` to be inactive add a class. You can then use `document.getElementsByClassName` to target multiple DOM elements and do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, if you are trying to style the elements using the ID, use the classes instead of ids.

Let's suppose you do not want use jQuery ( otherwise you would already do that ).

The elements are all inactive:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="navbar">
  <li class="inactive" id="home"><a href="#Home" onclick="load_home()">HOME</a></li>
  <li class="inactive" id="products"><a href="#Products"   onclick="load_products()">PRODUCTS</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
function make_all_inactive() {
  var childs = document.getElementById("navbar").childNodes;
  for(var i = 0; i<childs.length; i++) {
    var child = childs[i];
    if (child.tagName === 'LI') {
      child.className = "inactive";
    }
  }
}

function load_home(){
  make_all_inactive();
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='that is your homepage';
  document.getElementById("home").className = 'active';
}
```

**CSS**

```
.active a {
  color: red;
}

.inactive a {
  color: blue;
}

#navabar li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Whay you are lodaing the pages with innerHTML is not the in the reason of your question, but be carefull that the innerHTML could not parse eventual active javascript that is there. Is not a best practice.
Also consider that the link itself A is not used, you can remove it, and just make with css the cursor appear as a link over the LI.

Other than this, of course the code can be optimized in a lot of ways, not writing a function for every page. But i think this is out of topic.

**JSFIDDLE**

JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/asturur/wmoL7bhg/

Comment: you get what i mean. but the class is not changing from inactive to active.

If  i cant use .innerHTML to load other html file what should i do to create a one page website that the content is the only part that is changing. not the whole page.

how can i change the class of Li?

Comment: Probably i tiped code without checking, i 'm gonna open a fiddle to show you.

Answer (score 0):

The other comments indicate the code snippet you presented does not follow the best practices. Indeed it is recommended to use classes rather than id values. This does not exactly answer your question, however, instead it is more in line with figuring out the context of your question and discussing the context.

In regards to the posed question. I played with your code snippet in Firefox, and its behavior was different. First, `document.getElementById("content")` evaluated to null, so its `.innerHTML` did not go through. After commenting out the whole statement, the *if* guard evaluated to false, so the *then* branch could not be tested. Then I modified the html so that the *if* guard evaluated to true. In other words, there was an element with `id=inactivehome` (there was not one before). The code in the *then* branch changed it, as written. No other id changes happened because there was no other elements with the listed id values. Finally, I added an element with an id from that list, and then the code in the *then* branch changed that id as well.

Therefore it seems the answer, in the narrow sense, is: there were no html elements with the other id values.